# Spring Cloud Stream Producer adds "junk" characters when using Spring Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Our microservices are using JDK 8, Spring Cloud Stream API with Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE for producing messages onto Kafka Queue. For the Consumer API, we are using Spring Kafka 1.1.2.RELEASE, specifically `@KafkaListener`. Message type is application json

We notice that the consumers have some junk characters appended to the message near the "contentType", which is indicated below: [JunkCharsInConsumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJzOd.png)

When using vanilla Apache Kafka Client API 0.10.2.1 with JDK 8, we still see junk characters in the received messages.

Its only when we use Cloud Stream `SINK` that we are able to retrieve the messages without any junk characters.

Is this an issue or is there some setting in the Producer/Consumer that we may be missing out on? Please advise if additional details are required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the producer `headerMode` to `raw`.

See [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_producer_properties).

> **headerMode**
>
> When set to `raw`, disables header embedding on output. Effective only for messaging middleware that does not support message headers natively and requires header embedding. Useful when producing data for non-Spring Cloud Stream applications.
>
> Default: `embeddedHeaders`.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the details, Gary. Just so you know this did not  fix the problem. 
So for the time being we have converted the response to byte array in consumer and have done a character comparison, picking up the content from the first character we know is clean after the junk. 
Long-term approach to come down the line is to use StreamListener in the consumer

Comment: You must have misconfigured something - I can assure you that raw `headerMode` will NOT add those headers to the message body.